# Filter pbf file for OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osmfilter

I want to filter `PBF file` for `OpenStreetMap` by highways. For example `highways = residential`. I'm novice in `OpenStreetMap`. I read some info and start to use these tools to get results, they are `osmfilter`, `osmconvert`, `osmosis`

Stages:

1) I convert pbf-file to osm, for using it in osmconvert. For example:osmconvert norway.pbf >norway.osm

2) I filter osm-file via osmfilter, result file I get in pbf-format. For example: osmfilter norway.osm.pbf --keep="highway=primary =secondary waterway=river" >streets.osm

3) In final I process filtered pbf-file via osmosis

My problem is filtered pbf file is in an `application/xml` format, but `osmosis` works with pbf file which is in `application/octet-stream` format. How to fix it? Or which filter methods are better? May be I need change `application/xml` format to `application/octet-stream`. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

osmosis can read XML and PBF files. Just use `--read-pbf` for PBF files and `--read-xml` for XML files.

Alternatively consider using [osmium-tool](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool) instead. See the [manual](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html) for [filtering by tags](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#filtering-by-tags).